# Compare two sentences word by word and return the number of word matches with some conditions

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of code to compare two sentences word by word and return the number of word matches with some conditions:

**hint:** the word in the first sentence ::::  the word in the second sentence

1)   **protecting**  ::::  **i**      should result **Not matched**

2)   **protecting**  ::::  **protect**      should result **matched**

3)  **protect**   ::::  **protecting**  should result **matched**

4)  **him**   ::::  **i**  should result **Not matched**

5)  **i**   ::::  **i**  should result **matched** but only once not twice: (let me explain this)

We have this string as the **first sentence**:

```
 let speechResult = "they're were protecting him i knew that i was aware";
```

It has two **i** as you see but there is only one **i** in the **second sentence** here:

```
let expectSt = ['i was sent to earth to protect you'];
```

So we should consider this match as one occurrence not two, If we had two **i** occurrences in the second sentence too, then we would consider the **i** matches as two occurrences.

6)  **was**   ::::  **was**  should result **matched**

Here is my code so far:

```js
// Sentences we should compare word by word
let speechResult = "they're were protecting him i knew that i was aware";
let expectSt = ['i was sent to earth to protect you'];
    
// Create arrays of words from above sentences
let speechResultWords = speechResult.split(/\s+/);
let expectStWords = expectSt[0].split(/\s+/);

// Here you are..    
//console.log(speechResultWords)
//console.log(expectStWords)
        
// Count Matches between two sentences
function includeWords(){
// Declare a variable to hold the count number of matches    
let countMatches = 0;    
for(let a = 0; a < speechResultWords.length; a++){
        
    for(let b = 0; b < expectStWords.length; b++){
          
        if(speechResultWords[a].includes(expectStWords[b])){
           console.log(speechResultWords[a] + ' includes in ' + expectStWords[b]);
           countMatches++
        }
              
    }  // End of first for loop  
    
} // End of second for loop
    
return countMatches;
};
    
// Finally initiate the function to count the matches
let matches = includeWords();
console.log('Matched words: ' + matches);
```

Comment: What is your problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: I mentioned the problems in the conditions, please run the code snippet. The code I wrote assumes the `protecting` and `i` matched and ...

Comment: why ```protect``` and ```protecting``` match but ```i``` and ```him``` do not? Is it based on stemming?, is it more simplistically based on common starting sequence (e.g: ```super``` and ```show``` should match because of the s)?

Comment: I mean matching between words, as `i` is a single word and `him` is another word they should not be considered matched . `super` and `show` are different words so there is no match..

Comment: my question was almost rhetorical: why would protect and protecting be the same word? (you should emphase that on your original post since no answer so far has taken that constraint into account)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could count the wanted words with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and iterate the given words by checking the word count.

```js
function includeWords(wanted, seen) {
    var wantedMap = wanted.split(/\s+/).reduce((m, s) => m.set(s, (m.get(s) || 0) + 1), new Map),
        wantedArray = Array.from(wantedMap.keys()),
        count = 0;

    seen.split(/\s+/)
        .forEach(s => {
            var key = wantedArray.find(t => s === t || s.length > 3 && t.length > 3 && (s.startsWith(t) || t.startsWith(s)));
            if (!wantedMap.get(key)) return;
            console.log(s, key)
            ++count;
            wantedMap.set(key, wantedMap.get(key) - 1);
        });

    return count;
}

let matches = includeWords('i was sent to earth to protect you', 'they\'re were protecting him i knew that i was aware');

console.log('Matched words: ' + matches);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what is the rule for starting words? what happens with short words like *a* or *i*? should the `startsWith` approach have a minimum length?

Comment: @Nina Scholz `should the startsWith approach have a minimum length?` could you please explain this a bit more, please?

Comment: if you have no length, then `a` matches against `alert`. is this intended?

Comment: No... That is not good... Where in your code you defined that length? What if we want to match only when more than 2 letters match between words?

Comment: it is this part: `s.length > 3 && t.length > 3`

Comment: What if we have `protecting` against `protected`?

Comment: Mmmmm... That would be perfect if `protecting` and `protected` return a match...

Comment: hm. do you have a rule for that? thinkable would be to remove *-ing* or *-ed* or maybe other parts of flections.

Comment: There are 7 letters that match (considering letter order) between `protecting` and `protected` ... What if we include those words with more than half of their length matching with other words in the second sentence ( For `protecting` match words in sentence 2 if it matched at least 5 letters ) !!!

Comment: You're right again... Could we have an array for that like : `[ 'ed', 'ing', ...]`

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have a new question with the last requests?

Comment: @Nina Scholz new question has been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829018/compare-two-sentences-word-by-word-and-return-the-number-of-word-matches-conside

Comment: @Nina can you please provide a reference to learn about `get` and `set` methods you used in your code... I can't find anything googling those... Also is there any book video tutorials to learn bow to work with data structure...

Comment: it's just a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). `set` and `get` are methods to set and retrieve a value from the map. i don't have any resources. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```js
let speechResult = "they're were protecting him i knew that i was aware";
let expectSt = ['i was sent to earth to protect you'];


function includeWords(){
    let countMatches = 0;    
    let ArrayFromStr = speechResult.split(" ");
    let Uniq = new Set(ArrayFromStr)
    let NewArray = [Uniq]
    let str2 = expectSt[0]

    for (word in NewArray){
        if (str2.includes(word)){
            countMatches += 1
        }
    }

    return countMatches;
};


let matches = includeWords();
```

I get the speechResult, made it into a array, remove duplicates, convert to array again, and then check if the expectSt string contains every word on the NewArray array.

Comment: Updated, sorry about it.

Comment: It returns 0 instead of 3 matches

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the strings and update the index of the matched word with the empty string and store the matches in an array.

```js
let speechResult = "they're were protecting him i knew that i was aware";
let expectSt = ['i was sent to earth to protect you'];

// Create arrays of words from above sentences
let speechResultWords = speechResult.split(/\s+/);
let expectStWords = expectSt[0].split(/\s+/);

const matches = [];

speechResultWords.forEach(str => {
  for(let i=0; i<expectStWords.length; i++) {
    const innerStr = expectStWords[i];
    if(innerStr && (str.startsWith(innerStr) || innerStr.startsWith(str)) && (str.includes(innerStr) || innerStr.includes(str))) {
        if(str.length >= innerStr.length) {
          matches.push(innerStr);
          expectStWords[i] = '';
        } else {
          matches.push(str);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
});

console.log(matches.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) you intuit that words having the same stem are the same.

e.g

- for verb: protect, protected, protecting, ...
- but also plural: ball, balls

What you may want to do is:

1. stem the words: use some stemmer (which will have their pros & cons) (e.g PorterStemmer which seem to have a [js implem](https://github.com/kristopolous/Porter-Stemmer))
2. count the occurrence on that "stemmed space", which is trivial

NB: splitting with '\s' may not be enough, think about commas and more generally punctuation. Should you have more need, keyword for this is tokenization.

Below an example using PorterStemmer with some poor home made tokenization

```js
const examples = [
 ['protecting','i'],
 ['protecting','protect'],
 ['protect','protecting'],
 ['him','i'],
 ['i','i'],
 ['they\'re were protecting him i knew that i was aware','i was sent to earth to protect you'],
 ['i i', 'i i i i i']
]
function tokenize(s) {
  // this is not good, get yourself a good tokenizer
  return s.split(/\s+/).filter(x=>x.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9']/g,''))
}

function countWords(a, b){
  const sa = tokenize(a).map(t => stemmer(t))
  const sb = tokenize(b).map(t => stemmer(t))
  const m = sa.reduce((m, w) => (m[w] = (m[w] || 0) + 1, m), {})
  return sb.reduce((count, w) => {
    if (m[w]) {
      m[w]--
      return count + 1
    }
    return count
  }, 0)
}
examples.forEach(([a,b], i) => console.log(`ex ${i+1}: ${countWords(a,b)}`))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kristopolous/Porter-Stemmer/PorterStemmer1980.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will provide the primitive solution by comparing sentences' tokens. But here are two pitfalls that I can see:

1. You should compare both sentences' tokens in your main `IF` clause by an `OR` operand
2. You can add both occurrences in a `SET` collection to avoid any repetitions.

Comment: It seems to be so much more complicated than what I thought at first...

Comment: as you get deeper inside the problem it will expand to extreme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to get the count of all matched word between two sentence / set of strings.

```
function matchWords(str1, str2){
    let countMatches = 0;    
    let strArray = str1.split(" ");
    let uniqueArray = [...new Set(strArray)];
    uniqueArray.forEach( word => {
        if (str2.includes(word)){
            countMatches += 1
        }
    })
    return countMatches;
};
console.log("Count:", matchWords("Test Match Words".toLowerCase(),"Result Match Words".toLowerCase());
```

Above code is tested and working.