# Compare two sentences word by word and return the number of word matches considering different word forms

Tags: javascript

Thanks to [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) I have a code to compare two sentences word by word and return the number of word matches like this:

```js
function includeWords(wanted, seen) {
    var wantedMap = wanted.split(/\s+/).reduce((m, s) => m.set(s, (m.get(s) || 0) + 1), new Map),
        wantedArray = Array.from(wantedMap.keys()),
        count = 0;

    seen.split(/\s+/)
        .forEach(s => {
            var key = wantedArray.find(t => s === t || s.length > 3 && t.length > 3 && (s.startsWith(t) || t.startsWith(s)));
            if (!wantedMap.get(key)) return;
            console.log(s, key)
            ++count;
            wantedMap.set(key, wantedMap.get(key) - 1);
        });

    return count;
}

let matches = includeWords('i was sent to earth to protect you introduced', 'they\'re were protecting him i knew that i was aware introducing');

console.log('Matched words: ' + matches);
```

The code works fine, but there is still one issue:

What if we want to return a match for `introduced` and `introducing` too?

Comment: That is vague: does "introduced" match "introduction", "introductory", "intro", ...? What are the rules? Do you have a closed list of words that should be considered the "same"?

Comment: you could probably have some code that would check words for common conjugation endings, like `.*(ed|ing)`...but given how quirky English is, I would imagine you'd end up with very complex code to handle all of the exceptions to the exceptions to the exceptions.

Comment: Research Levenshtein distance/algorithm

Comment: Considering `protecting` and `protected`, There are 7 letters that match (considering letter order) between `protecting` and `protected` ... What if we include those words with more than half of their length matching with other word !!!

Comment: @Dexygen Not a Bad Idea...But it makes the code too slow...

Comment: What do you mean "too slow"?  How does it make it too slow?  How fast does it really need to be?  All this should be considered before you reject THE TRIED AND TRUE way to achieve what your after.

Comment: A standard and basic approach is to use stemming as I answered in your __previous__ post.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the program to consider the words 'introduce' and 'introducing' as a match, it would amount to a "fuzzy" match (non binary logic). One simple way of doing this would require more code, the algorithm of which would possibly resemble

1. Take 2 words that you wish to match, tokenize into ordered list
   of letters
2. Compare positionally the respective letters, i.e
   match a[0]==b[0]? a[1]==b[1] where a[0] represents the first letter
   of the first word and b[0] represents the first tokenized
   letter/character potential match candidate
3. KEep a rolling numeric count of such positional matches. In this case it is 8   (introduc).
4. divide by word length of a = 8/9 call this f
5. divide by word length of b = 8/11 call this g
6. Provide a threshold value beyond which the program will consider it a match. eg. if you say anything above 70% in BOTH f and g can be
   considered a match - viola, you have your answer!

Please note that there is some normalization also needed to prevent low length words from becoming false positives. you can add a constraint that the aforementioned calculation applies to words with at least 5 letters(or something to that effect!

Hope this helps!!
Regards,
SR

Comment: Is it from your mind or do you have some reference? I'd be interested to read some: It feels like the short words may fail: quick, quickies have the same root but ies represent 30% of original word, but allowing such amount would not always be good: rack/racket, or for longer word: propertion/property. Anyway should you have some ref I'd be delighted

Comment: This was purely based on my thoughts - no reference material available -sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick fix solution.

It's not intended as a complete solution.
Since the English language has more than a few quirks that would almost require an AI to understand the language.

First add a function that can compare 2 words and returns a boolean.

It'll also make it easier to test for specific words, and adapt to what's really needed.

For example, here's a function that does the simple checks that were already used.
Plus an '...ed' versus '...ing' check.

```js
function compareWords (word1, word2) {
    if (word1 === word2) 
        return true;
    if (word1.length > 3 && word2.length > 3) {
        if (word1.startsWith(word2) || word2.startsWith(word1)) 
            return true;
        if (word1.length > 4 && word2.length > 4) {
           if (/(ing|ed)$/.test(word1) && word1.replace(/(ing|ed)$/, 'inged') === word2.replace(/(ing|ed)$/, 'inged'))
               return true;
       }
  }

  return false;
}

//
// tests
//
let words = [
  ["same", "same"],
  ["different", "unsame"],      
  ["priced", "pricing"],
  ["price", "priced"],
  ["producing", "produced"],
  ["produced", "producing"]
];

words.forEach( (arr, idx) => {
  let word1= arr[0]; 
  let word2= arr[1];
  let isSame = compareWords(word1, word2);     
  console.log(`[${word1}] ≈ [${word2}] : ${isSame}`);
});
```

Then use it in the code you already have.

```
...
    seen.split(/\s+/)
        .forEach(s => {
            var key = wantedArray.find(t => compareWords(t, s));
...
```

Regarding string similarity, here's f.e. an older SO post that has some methods to compare strings : [Compare Strings Javascript Return %of Likely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10473745/4003419)

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate similarites for a word pair and get a relation how many characters are similar bei respecting the length of the given word and the wanted pattern.

```js
function getSimilarity(a, b) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) break;
        i++;
    }
    return i / Math.max(a.length, b.length);
}

console.log(getSimilarity('abcdefghij', 'abc'));         // 0.3
console.log(getSimilarity('abcdefghij', 'abcdef'));      // 0.6
console.log(getSimilarity('abcdefghij', 'abcdefghij'));  // 1

console.log(getSimilarity('abcdef', 'abcdefghij'));      // 0.6
console.log(getSimilarity('abcdefghij', 'abcdef'));      // 0.6

console.log(getSimilarity('abcdefghij', 'xyz'));         // 0
console.log(getSimilarity('introduced', 'introducing')); // 0.7272727272727273
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this, it seems to work fine. any suggestions would be appreciated..

```js
let speechResult = "i was sent to earth to introducing protect yourself introduced seen";
let expectSt = ['they were protecting him knew introducing that you i seen was aware seen introducing'];

// Create arrays of words from above sentences
let speechResultWords = speechResult.split(/\s+/);
let expectStWords = expectSt[0].split(/\s+/);

function includeWords(){
// Declare a variable to hold the count number of matches    
let arr = [];    
for(let a = 0; a < speechResultWords.length; a++){
        
    for(let b = 0; b < expectStWords.length; b++){
          
        if(similarity(speechResultWords[a], expectStWords[b]) > 69){
           arr.push(speechResultWords[a]);
           
           console.log(speechResultWords[a] + ' includes in ' + expectStWords[b]);

        }
              
    }  // End of first for loop  
    
} // End of second for loop
    let uniq = [...new Set(arr)];
    return uniq.length;
};

let result = includeWords();
console.log(result)


// The algorithmn
 function similarity(s1, s2) {
        var longer = s1;
        var shorter = s2;
        if (s1.length < s2.length) {
            longer = s2;
            shorter = s1;
        }
        var longerLength = longer.length;
        if (longerLength == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerLength)*100;
    }

    function editDistance(s1, s2) {
        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

        var costs = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
            var lastValue = i;
            for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
                if (i == 0)
                    costs[j] = j;
                else {
                    if (j > 0) {
                        var newValue = costs[j - 1];
                        if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                            newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                                costs[j]) + 1;
                        costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
                        lastValue = newValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i > 0)
                costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
        }
        return costs[s2.length];
    }
```

Comment: you should write somewhere that you used levenshtein as the string metric (if this is it). There are plenty of [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric). You may compare them (if not for perf, for curiosity)